# I keep getting this "InvalidOperationException: Multiple handlers matched." and I don't know what to do, can somebody help me?

Tags: c#

```cs
namespace AlanKardek.Pages.Prof_View;

public class AlunoModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly AlanKardekContext _context;

    public AlunoModel(AlanKardekContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    public IList<Usuario> Usuario { get; set; } = default!;

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        if (_context.Usuarios != null)
        {
            Usuario = await _context.Usuarios.ToListAsync();
        }
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Curso Curso { get; set; } = default!;

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null || _context.Curso == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var curso = await _context.Curso.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        if (curso == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        Curso = curso;
        return Page();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to select all the itens in the Usuario table, and select the item in the Curso table witch has the id = the previous id

[image]

Comment: Never post screenshots from text. Please post the text as text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you make a request for a page in AspNetCore (Razor pages), it looks at the controller (the class you've shown) and tries to find a handler (`OnGetAsync`, `OnPostAsync`, etc.) that can handle the request it's received.

This exception is telling you that multiple handlers matched the request and it doesn't know which one to use.

The reason for this is that, when id isn't provided, either `OnGetAsync()` **or** `OnGetAsync(int? id)` (passing `null`) would be acceptable.

So just change your `OnGetAsync(int? id)` method to make the parameter non-nullable, and forego the null check:

```cs
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    // ...
}

// ...

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int id)
{
    // ...
}
```